# Magento2 move block

Tags: magento2

I tried to replace the default discount block. Unfortunately, the block is always located on the bottom of the container. I can't move it to the default block position.

my xml -

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    -->
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <remove name="checkout.cart.coupon"/>
        <referenceContainer name="cart.discount">
            <block class="{namespace}\Coupons\Block\Coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon2" as="sadasdasd" template="test.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="cart.discount" destination="checkout.cart.container" before="checkout.cart.order.actions.gift_options" />
    </body>
    </page>
```

screen of result - 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think checkout.cart.order.actions.gift_options is not an immediate child of checkout.cart.container, so the 'before' clause is not finding position you want and is defaulting to 'last child' as a default behavior.

Comment: so, we have this code on default layout - `<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="cart/shipping.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="cart/coupon.phtml"/>` I try to use `<referenceContainer name="cart.discount">
            <block class="{name}\Coupons\Block\Coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon2" as="coupon2" template="coupon.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="coupon2" destination="with-items" after="shipping" />`

Comment: but this code didn't work. Maybe you can give me working example of code?